# Unknown input format: 'x11grab' on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, selenium-webdriver, headless

I tried to record video of my Selenium tests using 'Headless' gem.

```
@headless = Headless.new(video: {
    codec: 'libx264',
    frame_rate: 25,
    log_file_path: STDERR,
})
@headless.start
@browser = BrowserProvider.set_browser
@headless.video.start_capture
```

but when Im trying to start recording I got an error `Unknown input format: 'x11grab'`
Is any way to do it on Mac os?

Comment: I don't think you'll have luck with headless gem on OSX. I don't know what BrowserProvider but you can get Watir working with headless chrome or firefox.